# Is it safe to use non-genuine laptop's battery

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life, charging, voltage

I own an Hp pro-book 430 G2 Laptop, While I found batteries compatible with this model they weren't exactly the same. My battery is RA04XL while What I found has RA04 written on it.

Both batteries Li-ion have the same voltage (14.8V) but my old one is 40 Wh while the new one is 44 Wh my old one has a capacity of 2550 mAh while the new one is 2850 mAh.
So is it safe or not to use my new battery (Produced in china - not original)
Edit:Still waiting for answer to the first part.
**Please try to answer my question then tell me what can cause this issue:**
When I installed the new battery I smelled a burn near my laptop's fan (For sure not the battery) what can cause this?

Comment: Generally it is OK to use non-oem batteries so long as they produce the required energy levels and are from a reputable source. There is nothing inherently wrong with using aftermarket replacement batteries. For your question about what is causing that smell: we cannot tell. You'll have to get a qualified hardware technician to look at the computer.

Comment: But is the new one compatible since it has 44 Wh while the old is only 40? will it explode because of that? @music2myear

Comment: If the battery is the same physical size it is probably mislabelled. It is not possible for anyone to authoratively advise, but even aftermarket batteries are typically safe. Generally its the charging circuitry or bad design with respect if current draw or physical room/heating that causes batteries to combust. Im pretty sure there is nothing inherent in charger circuitry limiting the capacity (but charge times will be longer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to use a different battery](https://superuser.com/questions/1460887/is-it-safe-to-use-a-different-battery)